# Session ID isn't registering as being set unless the page is refreshed after user signs in

Tags: php, sessionid, isset

I have a number of front-end functions which are triggered based on whether or not a user is signed in (i.e. the menu items displayed), but I'm having trouble triggering them when a user signs in unless they are redirected or the page is refreshed.

How can I change the value of `$logged_in` to be set once a user logs in? The functions are all working properly, including setting `$_SESSION['SESS_USER_ID'] = $member['user_id'];` once they're signed in.

**Index.php** *(much of this code is also used throughout the site)*

*At the beginning of the document:*

```
<?php    
require_once('auth.php'); // This file starts session, and checks if(!isset($_SESSION['SESS_USER_ID']) || (trim($_SESSION['SESS_USER_ID']) == ''))  
require_once('config.php'); // Connects to database connection   
$user_id = $_SESSION['SESS_USER_ID'];       
$logged_in = (isset($_SESSION['SESS_USER_ID']));
?>
```

The relevant functions are then triggered by $logged_in, and follow this basic format:

```
<?php if ($logged_in) : ?>
// Some HTML or Script
<?php else : ?>
// Some HTML or Script
<?php endif; ?>
```

*Sign In form & function*

*My apologies if some of the AJAX is irrelevant - I don't really know AJAX and re-purposed existing code.*

```
<form id="loginForm" name="loginForm" action="login-exec_pdo.php"  method="post">  
<label for="user_name">Username </label><input type="text" name="user_name" required />
<label for="password">Password </label><input type="text" name="password" required />
<div id="return_result"></div><div id="messageBox5">Please complete the highlighted    fields</div>                  
<input type="submit" id="login" value="Sign in" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () { $('#loginForm').validate({          
rules: {user_name: {required: true, minlength: 2,}, password: {required: true, minlength: 6,},}, messages: {user_name: "", password: "",},      
errorLabelContainer: "#messageBox5", 
submitHandler: function (form){
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'login-exec_pdo.php',
    data: $("#loginForm").serialize(),
    success: function(data) {   
      if(data == "true") {
        $("#loginForm").fadeOut("fast");
      }
      else {
        writeToTarget('return_result', 'Incorrect Username or Password');
}  }  });  }   });  });  
</script>
```

**The login-exec.php file**

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once('config/config_pdo.php'); // Includes db connection, salt, & PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
$password = $_POST['password'];  
$hashedPassword = sha1($salt . $password); 

try {  
   $stmt_user = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM customer_info WHERE user_name = :user_name and password = :hashedPassword");  
   $stmt_user->bindValue(':user_name', $_POST['user_name'], PDO::PARAM_STR); 
   $stmt_user->bindValue(':hashedPassword', $hashedPassword);     
   $stmt_user->execute();                 
   session_regenerate_id();                  
   $member = $stmt_user->fetch();                 
   if($member) {                  
      $_SESSION['SESS_USER_ID'] = $member['user_id'];  
      $_SESSION['SESS_USER_NAME'] = $member['user_name'];             
      session_write_close(); 
      echo "true";                 
      exit();
   }else {
      echo "false";
      exit();
   }                    
}catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}                 
?>
```

I've also tried using both javascript and php to set it in the success function within the Sign In function (where indicated above), but it either didn't set it and/or prevented the login function from completing properly.  Some of the things I've tried are:  `if ($logged_in) :`  `$logged_in = (isset($_SESSION['SESS_USER_ID']));`  `$logged_in = "true";`  and  `$logged_in = 1;`

Comment: one question: `... data: $("#loginForm").serialize()`  you need to unserialize in PHP the `$_POST['data']`. Did you do that?

Comment: oh now I got: you should set `$logged_in = true` before `echo "true";` try this. it should work

Comment: @metal_fan: I just tried your suggestion of setting $logged_in = true before echo "true", but unfortunately that's causing it to echo "true" on login-exec.php (instead of keeping the user on the original page)

Comment: @metal_fan: I actually repurposed this from another script, so I'm not sure if that's even necessary here because nothing's actually getting posted, it's just being used to select information from the db (I've updated the question to include that query)

Comment: I'm kinda confused, are you doing AJAX-authorization including form validation, right? The bad thing is that you do not track actions regarding both success and failure, so that it makes a bit harder to figure out what exactly goes wrong...

Comment: Let me repeat again, that I've noticed so far, you did not unserialization in php right after `..data: $("#loginForm").serialize() ... `right?

Comment: I've just noticed that it's not that hard to break your system... `$logged_in` isn't really reliable. Why not to create simply class that would handle all this stuff like, `$profile->isLogged()`, `$profile->getUsername()` `$profile->logout()`

Comment: @metal_fan: I'm using this jquery validation http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/ to validate that they've entered the required fields (user_name & password), and then the php query checks the db to confirm that the information is correct and to associate this user's session id with their user_id (and it does all that correctly). Just to clarify what you asked about unserializing it in php - I don't, do I need to if I'm specifying $password = $_POST['password']; $hashedPassword = sha1($salt . $password); and I'm binding them in the query?

Comment: @metal_fan: I'd love to try your suggestion of creating a class to handle this. Do I put that code in the php where I had $logged_in = (isset($_SESSION['SESS_USER_ID'])); ? Is there anything else that I'd need to do in addition to that?

Comment: I'm gonna post a very long answer. Which php version do you use?

Comment: I'm using version 3.01 on my computer, but my hosting company probably has a more recent version - should I find out which one they use?

Comment: whaaatttttt!???!!!?? PHP 3.01 Are you sure???!! It's extremely outdated 1998-2001 years (if I remember properly). Please create a dummy script and put this `<?php echo PHP_VERSION; ?>` What does it tell?

Comment: You're totally right - I have v5.2 on my computer :-) (For some reason, the license.txt file listed the version as 3.01 :-( ). And when I added the script and checked it on my site it echo'd 5.2.17 :-)

Comment: Ok. Before I post an answer, just another question: Do you have some validations for both username and password in PHP ?! or are you totally relying  on jquery-validate plugin?

Comment: I'm just using the jquery-validate plugin to check that they actually entered something (and generate an error message if they didn't). The php then compares what they've entered to what's in the db to make sure that what they've entered is valid. I was doing that because I find it easier to generate the error messages that way, but if that's a problem I could do the validation in php if necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're submitting the login request via AJAX, the main page's PHP won't be affected, since it's server-side and already written. If you're stuck on making the call through AJAX, you could:

1) Use the success() function to refresh the dialog/frame/whatever with the page that uses the $logged_in variable

2) Use the success() function to make another AJAX call to retrieve the page

3) Load everything (depending on how sensitive it is), but set the "logged in" material to `display:none;`, and use success() to do something like `$('.logged-in-user-stuff').show();`

Comment: I should add that option #3 won't work if you're showing user-specific data (e.g., "Welcome <?=$user;?>"), but would be fine for something like changing a menu to show "Logout" instead of "Login" and "Register".

Comment: I love how simply you laid out the options :-) #3 is actually what I'd been trying to do initially and couldn't get it to work :-D Would you mind showing me how to do that? Also, since it sounds like I may need to do either options 1 or 2, are there any important differences between refresh and retrieve? I know how to refresh (by using window.location in js), but since I don't know how how to retrieve a page in AJAX I figured I should ask :-)

Comment: This is actually one of the few forms which I'm submitting via AJAX - most of my forms are submitted entirely in php :-) I'm only using it on the forms where I wanted to use jQuery validation (forms with required fields or email addresses, or if I want to check inline that a username is available). I found it easier for generating validation error messages and I liked some of the user experience that came along with it (and to be honest, the only reason I used AJAX for this is because the clearest tutorial I'd found used it). Would you recommend that I try and change either one of these?

Comment: Check this out for a quick example: http://jsfiddle.net/bF9fB/ Use the login/logout links to see it in action. Basically, you'd just use .hide() and .show() inside the AJAX success() call. You should return something in your php like "die('authorized')" or "die('error')" so that the AJAX call can determine what the outcome of the PHP script was. (Success is "successful ajax call", not necessarily "successful login").  There are no (for-all-intents-and-purposes) significant differences between #1 and #2, other than how the user perceives the experience.

Comment: ran out of space.. To load the page through ajax, I've typically done this through an iframe. Refreshing the page may be better (particularly if it's a whole page), but then there's no point in AJAX. You can use jQuery to validate, and do something like $("#myForm').submit(); after a successful validation, and avoid the AJAX altogether. There are some decent plugins for jQuery form validation..  You may want to check out this list: http://speckyboy.com/2010/06/22/50-jquery-plugins-for-form-functionality-validation-security-and-customisation/

Answer (score 1):

**Intro**

It hurts my brain a bit, so let me show your obvious mistakes, first

**Mistake #1**
You can't set a PHP variable using JavaScript directly. This can done only by exchanging with JSON/XML

```
submitHandler: function (form){

    $.ajax({type: 'POST', url: 'login-exec_pdo.php', data: $("#loginForm").serialize() ...

    success: function(data) {

        if (data == "true") { 

            $("#loginForm").fadeOut("fast");

            // THIS IS WHERE I'VE TRIED TO SET $logged_in


            // 1. You can't set $logged_in to true right from this point
            // You should send JSON or XML back to PHP invoking a new nested ajax call
            // and then parse that stuff in PHP and then send the parsed stuff back to JavaScript.
            // However, this is some kind of bad approach, because A) you invoke a nested ajax call
            // B) you make it even worse to debug and maintain C) 

            // 2. You serialized the form but never used it

        ....
```

**Mistake #2**

Mixed responsibilities and code duplication.
What exactly : Mixing database handler (including db configuration) with user responsibility (see descriptions below)

```
$stmt_user = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM customer_info WHERE user_name = :user_name and password = :hashedPassword");  <-- LIMIT 1 keyword should be appended
$stmt_user->bindValue(':user_name', $_POST['user_name'], PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$stmt_user->bindValue(':hashedPassword', $hashedPassword); //<-- btw, you've missed PDO::PARAM_STR here
$stmt_user->execute();
...                
session_regenerate_id();  //<-- This should be done after successful authorization, not before                  
$member = $stmt_user->fetch();                 
if($member) {    //if you have error_reporting(E_ALL) you'll see a E_NOTICE 
   $_SESSION['SESS_USER_ID'] = $member['user_id'];
   session_write_close(); 
   echo "true"; //<-- Single quotes should be used instead of double ones.
   exit();
}else {
   echo "false";
   exit();
}
```

So, ok. Assume that's a login page. But in a real-word scenarion, the profile page of the user would use a database as well.
According to your code, you would have to implement the same database handler twice or even more... (see comments below)

**Mistake #3**
No error tracking at all & rely on client-side validation.

Basically, you should never trust client-side validation, because anyone could just simply disable JavaScript in a browser. 
And then he can easily send "invalid" data to the PHP script. Always do Server-Side validation!
But it does not mean that you should never use client-side validation at all.
Instead you should handle a situation when they come from browsers that do not have JS enabled/support.
You can try it yourself, just disable JavaScript in your browser and then enter your site...

**Mistake #4**
Not to mention the code duplication, the code itself isn't well structured. This is how this SHOULD NOT BE.
Here I'm saying about both JavaScript and PHP codes...

**Now, how you should fix this**

I'm not sure if you are going to follow above advices (in case you don't have a time or a will), so that let me answer your original question first.

> How can I change the value of `$logged_in` to be set once a user logs
>   in?

In short: THIS IS A PHP VARIABLE ! And thus should be set in PHP
And it soulds like to me, even if you set `$logged_in` to TRUE once a user logs in, you've missed somewhere `session_start()`.
Howewer, don't use this variable at all! Instead define a function, like, `is_user_logged()` because it's more reliable and "catchable" if something goes wrong.
Ok, next,

To make a life easier just define these functions:

```
/**
 * Checks whether user logged in
 * 
 * @return boolean TRUE if user is logged in
 *                 FALSE if not
 */
function is_user_logged(){
   //if session isn't started yet
   if ( session_id() == ''){
      // do start it now
      session_start();
   }

   if ( isset($_SESSION['SESS_USER_ID']) ){
      return true; 
   }

   return false;
}

/**
 * Retrieves an ID of the logged user if he's really logged
 * NULL otherwise
 * 
 * @return string|null
 */
function get_logged_user_id(){

   if ( is_user_logged() === TRUE ){
      return $_SESSION['SESS_USER_ID'];
   }

   return null;
}


/**
 * "Marks" given user id as a logged one
 * 
 * @return void
 */
function register_user_id_as_logged($id){

   //will start session also if not started yet
   if ( is_user_logged() !== TRUE ){
      $_SESSION['SESS_USER_ID'] = $id;
   }
}
```

Put these function at the top of the document.

Now change:

**#1 in HTML template**

```
<?php if ( TRUE === is_user_logged() ) : ?>

// Some HTML or Script if logged

<?php else : ?>

// Some HTML or Script if not logged

<?php endif; ?>
```

**#2**

```
...
$member = $stmt_user->fetch();                 
if($member) {                  
   $_SESSION['SESS_USER_ID'] = $member['user_id'];                 
   session_write_close(); 
   echo "true";
   exit;
```

to:

```
$member = $stmt_user->fetch();                 
if ($member) {  //<-- Somehow my heart tells me it should be - if ( isset($member[0]) )

   register_user_id_as_logged($member['user_id']); //<-- and this should be $member[0]['member_id']
   session_regenerate_id();
   exit('true');



if (data == "true") { 


$("#loginForm").fadeOut("fast"); // <-- not required if you're going to do redirect


// THIS IS WHERE I'VE TRIED TO SET $logged_in  <-- if you already in this "block", a "session id" is already set and it "works"
// all you need to do is just to redirect,like:

window.location = 'some_profile_page.php';
```

**Now my own recomendations**

**Tip #1**

Make sure the JavaScript isn't disabled.
You can simply do this, like,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

...

<!--So, when JS is disabled, it would redirect to /error.php page automatically -->
<noscript>

    <meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0; url=/error.php" />

</noscript> 

 ...
</head>


...
</html>
```

Use this trick in all your HTML documents.

**Tip #2**

You should encapsulate all profile related logic into a class.
It should be similar to this one:

```
class Profile {

    private $db;

    public function __construct(PDOAdapter $db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
    }


    public function login($username, $password)
    {
        //do query here and return boolean
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        //destroy session here
    }


    public function isLogged()
    {
        // check if session key exists and its a valid one here
    }

    private function registerAsLogged()
    {
        //....
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow! I'm learning so much right now :-D This is going to take me some time to fully understand so I'm 1rst going to try to figure out the part between 'Now, how you should fix this' and 'Tip #1' :-) One thing that I wanted to clarify is that #2 isn't in the HTML template, it's in login-exec.php. What's in the main document is what I referred to as 'The Sign In function' (which passes information back & forth between login-exec.php). Just to be sure I'm being clear, I'll update the code now to include all the relevant pieces. Does that change anything about your approach?

Comment: I wasn't sure from your notes if this would still require redirecting users if they log in successfully. My initial intention was intention was to avoid the need for that since they often need to remain on the page that they're on (I hadn't realized that there were other problems with my code, so I'm glad I was trying to do this ;-)). Also, would you mind showing me how to use is_user_logged() to trigger a javascript function too? Some of the functions (i.e. show/hide) would be much simpler to do in js than php, I just couldn't get it to work with my previous method ;-)

Comment: :) "After they successfully logged in" they should see their own profile page. On failure, they should stay on the current page and get error message, right? If so, there are only two ways to do it: 1) On success, invoke a new ajax call via jquery and then replace entire `html tree` with ajax response. It would look like so: `success: function(respondFromPHP){ $("html").html(respondFromPHP);  }` 2) And the second approach is just to refresh the page :) basically this is done via `winow.location = 'current_page.php'` :)

Comment: :)) oh, yeah, btw, I never said you should invoke UI functions like `show()/hide()` using PHP. They have nothing to do with a server-side logic. They are merely `helpers`

Comment: No, they're not automatically being redirected on success :-( Most users will remain on the same page until they click on a link. Does that mean that I have to refresh the page?

Comment: I haven't made the changes yet :-) I figured I should wait until you saw my 1rst comment (about #2 not being in the main document) to see if that changed anything. I also realized that instead of saying that I was updating the code I should have clarified that I was updating the code in the question ;-) (it now includes the complete script)

Comment: I guess what I was wondering about is the format of "if ( TRUE === is_user_logged() ) :", and if I always need to stick to that format. The first time I'd ever seen a similar format was with "if ($logged_in) :", and I didn't understand it enough to be able to modify the script.

Comment: I tried switching data serialize, but that made data always equal false :-( I'm assuming that there's probably a syntax error?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22089/discussion-between-metal-fan-and-chaya-cooper)